# Configuring ScalaDoc task in Gradle to generate aggregated documentation

Tags: scala, groovy, gradle, documentation-generation, scaladoc

I have a multi module scala project in Gradle.  Everything works great with it, except the ScalaDoc.  I would like to generate a single 'uber-scaladoc' with all of the libraries cross-linked.  I'm still very new to groovy/gradle, so this is probably a 'me' problem.  Any assistance getting this setup would be greatly appreciated.

```
build.gradle (in the root directory)

// ...

task doScaladoc(type: ScalaDoc) {

    subprojects.each { p ->

        // do something here?  include the project's src/main/scala/*?
        // it looks like I would want to call 'include' in here to include each project's
        // source directory, but I'm not familiar enough with the Project type to get at
        // that info.
        // 
        // http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.scala.ScalaDoc.html

    }
}
```

The goal here would be able to just run 'gradle doScalaDoc' at the command line and have the aggregate documentation show up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It'd good idea to prepare any proof of concept at GH e.g., with input and desired output.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean... is the question not clear?  Input is a multi-module scala build.gradle, and output is a single scaladoc that contains the docs from the projects.

Comment: @fbl did you find a solution for this problem? I have the same problem.